Attribute to material
I downloaded the .obj result from this tool: https://huggingface.co/spaces/TencentARC/InstantMesh
When I open it in blender I have to switch to viewport shading/ color/ attribute to see the shade.
Is there a way to convert the attribute to a blender material ?
Thanks

In the object's material, you should be able to add either a Color Attribute Node or an Attribute Node, pick the attribute you want to use, and use it in your material in any way you want.

The Color Attribute node only works with "color attributes", whereas the Attribute node works with any type of attribute (E.G. from geonodes). Because the Color Attribute node only works with color attributes, it is able to give you a drop-down list of available color attributes in the current object, whereas the Attribute Node requires searching your attributes in the Properties Editor:

Any of these nodes work and do the job, use whichever you feel more comfortable with.
But remember that, since it's a material, you will be able to see these only in Material Preview or Rendered viewport shadings.

Do you mean this ? I added the images in the first post. You can see the attribute in the solid view but in preview everything is black. Am I missing something ?

Type "Color" in the Attribute Name Field (or whatever attribute you want to see in preview)

Finally! Thanks everybody.

I updated my answer to give more information. Please don't forget to upvote and click the checkmark icon in the top left corner.

About the upvote: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.". I can only thank you in comments for now.

well now you have 21rep :P
